# how to capture message from stored procedure into file?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I settled up output file location in SQL Server Enterprise Manager.
For Example: E:\logfile\job.log
How can i return a "success" or "failed" message from stored procedure into that file?
Please help me and many thanks!!

Comment: I'm using ms sever 2000.

Comment: How are you calling the SP?  From the SQL Agent, Enterprise Manager, DTS or a custom app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like [this](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/1467601/A-general-logging-t-sql-process-to-write-to-txt-files.htm):

> Step 1: For the information you wish to write out to a .txt file,
>   assign it to a variable... so if the rowset is the result of a query
>   just use the select

```
@myvar = query
```

> Step 2: Using another variable, call it @cmdtxt (varchar (255)), build a
>   command-line string with the following format:

```
select @cmdtxt = "echo " + @myvar + " >> drive:\path\filename.txt"
```

> Step 3: Execute this string using the extended stored procedure xp_cmdshell:

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmdtxt
```